# How to ignore touch on image view that is over tableview Cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

My app now is using Uitableview and I add imageview on each cell. 
When I test on simulator, the method 'didSelectRowAt' works fine.
But when I test on real device, that method don't call. It maybe when we click on cell, the event is only over imageview.

So is there anyway to ignore imageview event?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UtKT.png)

Comment: You can simply do this by disabling user interaction of imageView in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed you means this method : imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false   ??? It does not work

Comment: Anyway. Could you please update this question with code. What are you trying?